# IsDirty Flag Pattern

Tags: c#, .net

I have a base class for a BLL that includes the following function:

```
    public bool IsDirty { get; protected set; }

    internal void SetField<TParam>(ref TParam field, TParam value)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<TParam>.Default.Equals(field, value) == false)
        {
            field = value;
            IsDirty = true;
        }
    }
```

In the classes that inherit the base class I use this as a wrapper around the SET object, such as:

```
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set { SetField(ref _userName, value); }
    }
```

I use the IsDirty property to test to see if I need to issue an Update. If at least one of the properties changes then save to database. This works for most types but Collections and Lists can change without using set. I wrote a wrapper for the Collection to have an IsDirty flag on the List which could be tested for change:

```
    public class CollectionChangeTracked<T> : Collection<T>
    {
        public bool IsDirty {get; set;}

        public CollectionChangeTracked()
        {
            IsDirty = false;
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, T newItem)
        {
            base.InsertItem(index, newItem);
            IsDirty = true; 
        }

        protected override void SetItem(int index, T newItem)
        {
            base.SetItem(index, newItem);
            IsDirty = true;
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            base.RemoveItem(index);
            IsDirty = true;
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            base.ClearItems();
            IsDirty = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I now have to test both the Classe's IsDirty property and any CollectionChangeTracked.IsDirty flags for updates. I could create method that performs the test in one spot such as:

```
    public CollectionChangeTracked<ApplicationRole> RolesList
    {
        get { return _rolesList; }
        set { SetField(ref _rolesList, value); }
    }

    public override bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return ResolveIsDirty(); }
        protected set { _isDirty = value; }

    private bool ResolveIsDirty()
    { 
        bool returnValue;

        if (_isDirty || RolesList.IsDirty)
            returnValue = true;
        else
            returnValue = false;

        return returnValue;
    }
```

But it seems like I should be able to come up with a cleaner solution that would allow a Class that contains the Collection to subscribe to a change of IsDirty of the CollectionChangeTracked object and update the IsDirty based on that change. Is this the better approach and how would I implement?

Comment: @jgauffin Let me fix that for you: jgauffin = !jgauffin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an `ObservableCollection<T>` register to the `CollectionChanged` event and mark the IsDirty flag when the event is raised.

```
...

ObservableCollection<int> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
myCollection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

...

public void OnCollectionChanged( Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
   IsDirty = true;
}
```

Comment: the issue with ObservableCollection is that all consumers of it have to support INotifyPropertyChanged, so it could work for this case but I would limit the usefulness of the Collection, that is why I created CollectionChangeTracked().

Comment: the consumers do not have to support INotifyPropertyChanged, they can use it like any other collection. You only need the INotifyPropertyChanged interface if you are going to use Binding on the item in the collection, or binding to the collection property in your class.

Comment: so if I have a someone using this as a Source to GridView it would still be safe? If so that would work.

Comment: Should I try updating Base Class instead? Since the IsDirty flag inherited from the Base Class, then it would great if the Base Class was listening for any properties that would would raise that event within the Class that inherited the Base Class.

Comment: If you are using an `ObservableCollection` as an `ItemsSource` the GridView will update when items are added or removed from the collection. However, if the items in the `ObservableCollection` are no `DependencyObjects` and do not implement `INotifyPropertyChnaged` the items in the grid view will not update when a property of an item in the collection changes. That means that items can be added or removed but cannot be updated without replacing an existing item

Comment: your base class can use reflection to get all the properties that implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and register to the event. However, I think that it is better for the inheriting class that adds the property to also handle the collection changed event for that property.